# Fraction and If Statement not working Java

Tags: java, math

Im working on a program I need to finish tonight, and basically it does a cheep version of factoring...
The problem is, that its not giving me numbers, but NaN.
Heres my code:

Class 1(Part that deals with this program):

```
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("                   ~Factoring~");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("in a polynomial, there are 3 important numbers used");
        System.out.println("to figure out x. they are a, b, and c, shown below.\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t1x^2 +2x -3");
        System.out.println("\t\t^     ^   ^");
        System.out.println("\t\ta     b   c");
        System.out.print("\nPlease type a, b, and c here[a b c]: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();
        int c = input.nextInt();
        mathey factor = new mathey(a,b,c, chooser);
        System.out.print(factor.solvefact());
```

Class 2:

```
    public class mathey
    {
        double a,b,c;

double solution1;
double solution2;
double discriminant;
double x1 = 0;
double x2 = 0;
  public mathey(int aN, int bN, int cN)
{
    a = aN;
    b = bN;
    c = cN;
    discriminant = (b*b)-4*a*c;
    solvea();
    solveb();
}
public String solvea()
{
    solution1 = (-1*b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    x1 = solution1;
    if(discriminant > 0) 
    { 
        return"x = " + solution1; 

    } 
    else if(discriminant == 0) 
    { 
        return "x =  " + solution1; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        double root1complex = -b/(2*a); 
        double root1complex2 = Math.sqrt(-discriminant)/(2*a); 

        return root1complex + " + " + root1complex2 + " i "; 
    }
}
    public String solveb()
{
    solution2 = (-1*b - Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    x2 = solution2;
   if(discriminant > 0) 
    { 
        return"x = " + solution2; 

    } 
    else if(discriminant == 0) 
    { 
        return"x =  " + solution2; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        double root1complex = -b/(2*a); 
        double root1complex2 = Math.sqrt(-discriminant)/(2*a); 

        return root1complex + " - " + root1complex2 + " i "; 
    }
}
public mathey(int aFact, int bFact ,int cFact, int chooser)
{
    a = aFact; b = bFact; c = cFact;
    discriminant = (b*b)-4*a*c;
    solvea();
    solveb();
    solvefact();
}
public String solvefact()
{
    String Answer = "";
    if((int)solution1 == solution1)
    {
         int wholeNum = (int)solution1/1;
         double numerator = (solution1%1) * 10;
         int denominator = 10;
         while(numerator > denominator) {
             denominator = denominator * 10;
            }   
         Answer+="("+denominator+"x + "+((denominator * wholeNum) + numerator)+")";

    }
    else
    {
        Answer +="( x + " +(solution1*-1) +")";



    }
    if((int)solution2 == solution2)
        {
            int wholeNum = (int)solution2/1;
            double numerator = (solution2%1) * 10;
            int denominator = 10;
            while(numerator > denominator) {
                denominator = denominator * 10;
            }   
            Answer+="("+denominator+"x + "+((denominator * wholeNum) + numerator)+")";


        }
        else
        {
          Answer +="( x + " +(solution2*-1) +")";  
        } 
    return Answer;
}
```

Heres the output:

```
    Choose a Way to Solve
    1. Quadratic Formula
    2. Factoring
    Which Method? [1/2]: 2
    --------------------------------------------------
                       ~Factoring~
    --------------------------------------------------
    in a polynomial, there are 3 important numbers used
    to figure out x. they are a, b, and c, shown below.

    1x^2 +2x -3
    ^     ^   ^
    a     b   c

    Please type a, b, and c here[a b c]: 1 2 -3
    (10x + 10.0)(10x + -30.0)
```

How Do I fix this, so I get the Output I should get? (x + 3.0)(x-1.0)

Comment: This can't be all of your code. Where are `solution1` and `solution2` declared and initialized? Why do you call `solvefact()` in the `mathey` constructor as well as in "Class 1?"

Comment: @MattBall Check now, I added 2 more methods. Basically, Solution1 and solution2 are declared as doubles, and used to store the answer of the quadratic formula

Comment: In all likelihood you're just dividing by zero somewhere.

Comment: If I am, then I cant find it :/

Comment: Do not use the modulus (`%`) operator on floating point numbers.  YOU WILL NOT GET THE EXPECTED RESULTS -- due to the way floats/doubles work.

Comment: First step to actually solve your problem is to run the code in an IDE and debug it line by line, watching the variables as they change and figuring out where things go wrong.

Comment: @JimGarrison what would be a good alternative? This is the only way I could think of..

Comment: `solvea()` and `solveb()` differ in a single character (`+` and `-`), and you should factor out the common code, using local variables and returning the result instead of using instance variables.

Comment: @JimGarrison I would do that, but solvea() and solveb() are being used by a different method, in a different portion of the program. Basically this program solves through quadratic formula, or solves by factoring. The factoring section is the one I am having problems with.

Comment: As to representing the roots as fractions, that is not practical.  Due to floating point representation errors you will end up with extremely long numerators/denominators.  For example, the number `1.1` cannot be stored exactly. It is stored as `1.10000000000000008881784197`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 4-param constructor `Mathey()` (which is the constructor you are calling) you are redeclaring the variables `a, b, c` and assigning the values passed in to them, masking the instance variables which remain equal to 0 (the default). These local variables are only in scope in the constructor. In `solveA()` and `solveB()`, `a, b, c` again refer to the instance variables (which are all 0), so you're dividing by `2*a` = 0, which makes `solution1` and `solution2` equal to `NaN`.

Change the line in the second constructor (if you continue to use it) from

```
double a = aN, b = bN, c = cN;
```

to

```
a = aN, b = bN, c = cN;
```

to solve the masking issue. You most likely want the instance variables to be `double`s rather than `int`s, though, so change

```
int a;int b;int c;
```

to

```
double a, b, c;
```

(you can do multiple declarations of the same type like this).

I don't know why you have two `Mathey` constructors, so either scrap the second one (what is `chooser?`) and just use the first, or make sure the second one also assigns a value to `determinant`.

This should be a start, anyway.

Comment: How would I fix this? I was thought that since a, b, and c are public variables, they would change when I assigned them values...

Comment: They normally do, but you redeclare local variables in `Mathey` with those same names, so accessing those names refers to the local variables, not the instance ones.

Comment: (That is, in the constructor `Mathey()`.)

Comment: Ok I did what you suggested, and im still having problems.. now I get a diffrent output.. Ill update the page with my new code and output

Comment: You need to use a debugger (or output the values of the variables at various places) so you can track what's going on. It's much more efficient than taking shots in the dark.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, Basically after all the problems, All that I had to change was the if statements from:

if((int)solution2 == solution2)

to

if((int)solution2 != solution2)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have the possibility your code by unit testing the functions.
For instance I noticed you used a {%} operator with a double number. That operator works with integers, and may drag the NaN result until the end.

You are also declaring variables in mathey() and then trying to use them in solvea() solveb() where they don't exist.

Comment: sorry, im pretty new to this, what do you mean by "check if you have the possibility your code by unit testing the functions'?

Comment: Hi, I meant to try and test separately your functions to check they work as expected. If you have a debugging tool with your developing  environment is also very helpful.
Did you check why you are using a number with decimal for a remainder % operation?

Comment: @Efren In java, the % operator is defined for floating point operands. See [15.17.3. Remainder Operator %](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3). It will give a NaN result if either input is a NaN, if the dividend is infinite, or if the divisor is zero.

Comment: Hi, Im using it to check if there is a decimal. As I understand, if you do a variable%1 it will equal 0 when there is no decimal, but it will be higher then 0 when there is a decimal. that section of code is used to convert the decimal to a fraction, to later display in String Answer

Comment: @patriciashanahan does this mean that solution1 and solution2 are both set at 0?

Comment: Thank you Patricia, but that does not mean the functions shown here work as expected.

Comment: @malymieczek Yes, variable%1 will be zero if the double variable is exactly an integer, but you need to be aware of floating point rounding issues. Many rationals are not exactly representable in double.